# cannot create scope of services in repository constructor asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I have transient-repository service, and I need to create scope of services every time I call it.

I've tried to create this scope in repository constructor like this:

```
public class ServiceRepository : IServiceRepository
{
    private IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    private IServiceScope _scope;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceContainer;

    private DataBaseContext _db;

    public ServiceRepository(DataBaseContext context, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _db = context;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        _scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        _serviceContainer = _scope.ServiceProvider;
    }
```

and after that I tried to call my repository service from service provider:

```
var serviceRepository = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceRepository>();
```

I expect that every time I call this service this way, a scope of services will be created which I declared in the repository constructor. But when accessing the service, I get the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve 'Data_Access_Layer.Interfaces.IServiceRepository' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'Data_Access_Layer.EF.DataBaseContext'.'
```

What am I doing wrong? before, I've set the scope like this and it worked:

```
var scopeFactory = _serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
var scopedContainer = scope.ServiceProvider;
```

But in this case I need to declare scope every time before I'm calling IServiceRepository. That is why I want to declare scope in IServiceRepository constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You're using all of this wrong. First, transient lifetime objects can be injected with scoped services directly. You should *not* inject `IServiceProvider` or `IServiceScopeFactory`, etc., but rather, your actual dependencies. You're *already* injecting your context directly (which is a scoped service), so I'm not sure why you're attempting to handle any thing else in a different way.

You should inject `IServiceProvider` (nothing else) only when your object has a singleton lifetime and needs scoped services. This is called the service locator anti-pattern, and it's an anti-pattern for a reason: you should avoid the need to do this as much as possible. In general, most of what people think should be singletons should actually not be singletons. There's only a handful of cases where you truly need a singleton lifetime. In all other scenarios, "scoped" should be your go-to lifetime. Additionally, if your singleton actually needs scoped services, that's a strong argument that it should actually be scoped itself.

However, if you *do* find yourself in a situation where you truly need a singleton lifetime *and* you still need scoped services, then correct way to do this is the following:

```
public class MySingletonService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

    public MySingletonService(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    ...
}
```

And that's it. You do not create a scope inside a constructor. Any service retrieved from a scope only exists within that scope, and when the scope is gone, so is the service. As such, you cannot persist scoped services to an ivar on a singleton. Instead, inside each individual method that needs such a service, you need to do:

```
using (var scope = _provider.CreateScope())
{
    var myScopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyScopedService>();
    // do something with scoped service
}
```

This is another reason why service locator is an anti-pattern: it leads to a lot of obtuse and repetitious code. Sometimes you have no choice, but most of the time you do.

Comment: While entirely correct from a DI design perspective, this is unfortunately a case where "performance optimization will often defy code abstractions" <= From Writing High Performance .NET.

"There's only a handful of cases where you truly need a singleton lifetime." <= Instead, you should be looking at each of your Scoped services as garbage collection overhead and attempting to move as many Scoped services to Singleton as possible.

Unless, of course, you're running on a Cray. Then everything will be fine.

Comment: I suppose I should add - once you see 3.8 seconds spent performing Gen 0 garbage collection in Azure production, then you start reevaluating allocations. Even short lived ones.

Comment: Singletons are/should be special purpose and created with that lifetime specifically because they *require* that lifetime, i.e. maintaining state across an entire application surface. Sure there may be a cost to allocation for using scoped, but that largely pays for itself in decreased code complexity and entropy. If your goal is to singleton everything, then you shouldn't really even be using dependency injection in the first place, and that will buy you greater performance than any hit from GC, anyways.

Comment: How does one recoup the cost of 3.8 second TTFB? You don't. That's top-line loss of sales in a variety of cases, including - Increased Bounce Rate - Decreased Cart Sizes - Abandoned Carts, etc. There are *many* ways you can refactor code in order to migrate what would otherwise be Scoped DI to Singleton. This should be just as much of a consideration, if not more, than design patterns for patterns sake. "Singleton everything" is just a straw man. Intelligent discrimination of tradeoffs is always necessary. But, "Scope everything" surely is not the best approach.

Comment: If you think I'm wrong, I'll have you send me a profiler of your code that you've written this way in production and I'll show you the effects of your suggestion in your production code right now. Message me for more details. Kind regards, Jeff

Answer (score 0):

While Chris Pratts answer provides the answer to "how do I get scoped services into a singleton" it is not an answer to why you are being told that your repository can't be resolved (at least when scope validation is still on).

### What is the root provider?

The root provider is the singleton provider that the runtime uses to source singleton services and all other services through scopes it creates. Its lifetime is tied directly to the application lifetime. If your writing a web api, the root provider will exist as long as your app is up.

> The root service provider is created when BuildServiceProvider is called. The root service provider's lifetime corresponds to the app/server's lifetime when the provider starts with the app and is disposed when the app shuts down

### What are scoped providers?

Scoped providers are used to create... you guessed it, scoped services. The lifetime of a scoped service is tied to the container that created it.

> Scoped services are disposed by the container that created them

A scope provides you, the developer, a way to define the lifetime of a particular service. In web projects, the creation of scope is typically handled by the request pipeline and that's all most scenarios need. The framework creates a scope for you when it starts to handle the request and uses the provider from that scope to inject services. When the request is complete, the scope is disposed of along with the services it controls. A manual version of this that exists in much of the msdn documentation would be as follows:

```cs
public void DoScopedWork(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
  using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
  {
    var scopedProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var myService = scopedProvider.GetService<IMyService>();
    myService.DoWork();
  }
}
```

### Scoped services from the root provider?

Scope validation is on in Development environments by default for a reason, and it's one of those if-you're-reading-this-you've-done-something-wrong kind of features.

> When ValidateScopes is set to true, the default service provider performs checks to verify that:
>
> - Scoped services aren't directly or indirectly resolved from the root service provider
> - Scoped services aren't directly or indirectly injected into singletons

Because scoped services are disposed of by the provider that created them when that provider is disposed (falls out of... scope?), creating a scoped service from the root provider effectively creates a singleton.

> If a scoped service is created in the root container, the service's lifetime is effectively promoted to singleton because it's only disposed by the root container when app/server is shut down. Validating service scopes catches these situations when BuildServiceProvider is called.

The validation exists for these cases because when the service was registered, the intent was explicitly stated that it should be scoped. So, telling the framework `IRepositoryService` should be scoped and then telling it to also resolve that scoped service from the root provider is a contradiction in terms. Of course the root provider CAN create this service, so the option to validate scopes CAN be turned off, but it's really best to understand what that could be doing to the app before deciding this is the right thing to do.

### But Transient, right?

Nope.
It was mentioned that the repository is supposed to be transient, but this doesn't mean we get to ignore scope. Transient services are new every time they're requested from the provider. Granted, a transient service requested from the root provider is *NOT* going to be a singleton, but it will be both new and undying (unless you dispose of it manually). We can imagine what is going to happen when a transient repository is requested ***n*** times from the root provider, right?

### Why is this a problem for OP

`var serviceRepository = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceRepository>();`
@Giacomo, this is a problem for you that is rooted in where you are trying to use the repository. Wherever in your code you are trying to resolve your repository is a place where a scoped provider hasn't been created for you. You are using the root provider. Without additional context about what you're actually doing with this repository, or when in the lifetime your doing it, what I can say is you are probably needing to create a scope first `using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope()) { ... }` and use the scoped service provider to create your repository.

### Correct, but not really

**Technically** your answer to your question could be considered correct, but it still doesn't get at what is happening. Instead of fixing the actual problem it ignores the warning and lets the scoped service (`DataBaseContext`) be promoted to an effective singleton because it is being created by the root provider to be injected into your repository (also an effective singleton). The most I could say for using `options.ValidateScopes = false` in your case is that it is a workaround.
*side note: it's not a good idea to let your db context exist as a singleton*

You mention that you want to feed the scope in which your repository should live to your repository. You can't have your cake and eat it too. This is a chicken-egg scenario. Creating the scope that is supposed to create your service is not something you can do in your service constructor. You say you don't want to create a new scope every time you need to use your repository. To me this sounds like your app was built around the service locator ***anti***-pattern as opposed to built with inversion of control in mind (which is what DI facilitates). If you insist on continuing to use the service locator, you should

1. get used to using `using (var s = _s.CreateScope()){...}`
2. hack your repository to implement a static accessor that will create the scope for you and execute your actions within its bounds 
   (btw: this is just as much an anti-pattern as service locator)
3. declare everything singleton or transient and expect memory leaks all over the place
4. use `options.ValidateScopes = false` and continue to ignore warning signs 
   (implicitly the same as option 3)

##### [Quoted Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0#scope-validation)

Answer (score -1):

I helps for me just add `.UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false)` to `BuildWebHos`t in `Program.cs` like this:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false)
            .Build();
```

I hope it will be useful for someone too